# Error C# in access on MONGO DB: Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1.

I'm an early C# programmer and I'm having problems accessing the Mongo DB database, does anyone have any tips to overcome this error?

https://github.com/VagnerBellacosa/009_API.NET_IntegradaAoMongoDB

Thank you in advance for your help, thank you very much and a great week everyone

Vagner Bellacosa

Comment: A couple of points... First, try to get a connection from the machine running the c# program using something like mongoshell.  Once you have determined your connection will be successful, try to connect using your app.  When reviewing your source code it appears you are trying to connect to a MongoDB Atlas cluster.  Atlas requires an IP Address whitelist, so make sure to include the IP address of the computer running the C# program in Atlas.  Lastly, user names are capitalization sensitive.  User API is not the same as user api.  Make sure to double-check connection settings.

Comment: Also, SASL is an LDAP concept.  SCRAM = Salted Challenge Response Authentication Mechanism, which is username/password, not LDAP, and thus not SASL.